# printf(): print literal escape characters (\10)

Tags: c, escaping, stdio

I feel like this question has been asked before, but i cant find the answer.

How do i use `printf()` to print out the literal of an escaped char?

For example i want:

```
char c = '\10';
printf(...,c);
```

To give me `\10`.

Or `char c = '\n'` to be printed as `\n` (not a newline).

---

Im currently using the format string like following:

```
char c = '\10';
printf("\\%d",(int) c);
```

Which gives me `'\13'`...

How do i get the  'literal' value of the char ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @WhozCraig Is my example not clear ?

Comment: How are you getting `\13` instead of `\8`?

Comment: First, your "currently using" example is not accurate. That code [does not produce your claimed output](https://godbolt.org/z/9rb3E8azK). Second, it sounds like you want to *translate* character escape sequences to their typographical representation. Translate = not going to happen without a translation step.

Comment: There is no difference between `'\b'` and `'\10'`, or `'\n'` and `'\12'` (on an ASCII machine).